# Client Server library for uploading files on C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, file-upload, client-server

What client-server library/framework on C# do you know for sending files? I need to create custom tool for uploading files to server; But i need something very simple. It will be very tiny utility;) I guess such library must wrap work with sockets because i cannot upload files using path like "\\ip\store".

Thank you for any advice!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason not to just use HTTP and [`WebClient.UploadFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx) in the client? The handling of the server side will depend on what you use to implement it, but [`HttpRequest.Files`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx) is likely to be useful.